# Does Spark Data Source V2 API support repartitioning of the input RDD for writes?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a custom Spark data source that is implemented using the Data Source V1 API which I am trying to convert to the V2 API.  In the V1 API, Spark passes the input `DataFrame` to the `createRelation` method of the `CreatableRelationProvider`:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/CreatableRelationProvider.html

By giving access to the input `DataFrame`, it allows re-partitioning of the input `RDD` prior to writing to the data source so that the number of input partitions is more suitable to the requirements of the target data source.

But in the V2 API, the `BatchWrite` interface doesn't seem to provide any way for the data source to force the input data to be re-partitioned prior to writing:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1a6708918b32e821bff26a00d2d8b7236b29515f/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala#L313

Spark will pass in the `PhysicalWriteInfo` containing the number of input partitions to `BatchWrite`, but the `BatchWrite` can't seem to have any influence over the number of partitions.

Is there any way to do this?  It seems like `BatchWrite` should have had a method that it could override that would allow it know in advance how many partitions are in the input `RDD` and allow it to return a different number of partitions if the `RDD` needs to be re-partitioned prior to writing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this support will not be available until Spark 3.2.0:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34255

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/write/RequiresDistributionAndOrdering.java